# Macbook Air WiFi Connection Timeout problem

Tags: macos, wifi

I have a Macbook Air 13" Early 2014 with macOS High Sierra 10.13.

The problem I have is that my Internet connection (Wi-Fi) keeps going off every 5 minutes or less.
When I start my Mac, Wi-Fi works perfectly, but after a few minutes, the Internet connection goes off. If I disconnect Wi-Fi and reconnect after a few seconds, the Internet connection works, but only for a few minutes, and then I have to disconnect and connect again.

When I connect the mac with others wifi works perfectly but the one at home gives me this problem only on my macbook. Because i have also an iphone and ipad and for them (the wifi that i use at home) works perfectly.

It's very annoying. I had the same issues with macOS Sierra, so I decided to update the OS, but it's the same.

If someone can help me I'll be really grateful, thanks.

Comment: without more information we can not answer. Give us more info on the WiFi it self. Do you have that problem when on another WiFi, like Starbucks. This is to determine if your WiFi service is the problem not your Mac.

Comment: Hi, when i connect the mac with others wifi works perfectly but the one at home gives me this problem only on my macbook. Because i have also an iphone and ipad and for them (the wifi that i use at home) works perfectly.

Comment: do you see many other strong signal WiFi around your home, if yes it could be the WiFi channel choice. Also if you have more then one WiFi spot in your home it could be trying to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting can be a process of elimination and often requires patience. Below are a few things you can try.

**Try another 'Wi-Fi' network**

It'd be interesting to see whether your MBA can maintain an internet connection from another Wi-Fi network. If you have an iPhone you can share an internet connection from its cellular connection and connect to that via your Mac's Wi-Fi port? Does this allow your MBA to browse the web, send/receive emails, etc and maintain the connection for longer than the five or so minutes you're having problems with?

Another way to test this is via a public Wi-Fi services (McDonalds, Starbucks, etc).

**Test your Wi-Fi network**

If your MBA connects fine to other Wi-Fi networks, then it's time to test your home Wi-Fi connection with other devices (such as an iPhone, iPad, etc) to see if they also drop a connection. If they do then you know it's your Wi-Fi network that needs investigating.

On the other hand, if they connect fine, it may be time to reboot your Wi-Fi router. This is because your router may have a limit on how many devices can be connected at any one time, or may struggle when too many devices are connected.

To do this, switch the router off for about a minute and then switch it back on. Wait a couple of minutes and then try connecting your MBA and testing to see what happens.

**Remove and then add back your Wi-Fi service**

I would totally remove your Wi-Fi service, restart, and add your Wi-Fi service back.

To do this:

- Go to Apple > System Preferences > Network
- Select the Wi-Fi service on the left-hand side
- Click on the cog icon at bottom-left and select Make Service Inactive
- Now delete the service by clicking on the minus sign (i.e. the <kbd>-</kbd> button) at left of the cog
- Click on the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button
- Exit Network preferences
- Restart your MBA
- Go to Apple > System Preferences > Network
- Click on the plus sign (i.e. the <kbd>+</kbd> button) at left of the cog
- In the pop-up window, ensure that Wi-Fi is selected from the drop-down menu
- Click on the <kbd>Create</kbd> button
- Make sure Wi-Fi is on and connected (it should remember your previous settings, but if not just re-add your Wi-Fi network again)

**Run Wireless Diagnostics**

You can use [Wireless Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25232?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) to analyse your Wi-Fi network. Follow these steps:

- Close any apps you have running
- Connect to the Wi-Fi network
- Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and go to the Wi-Fi status menu and select Open Wireless Diagnostics
- Enter your administrator name and password

Now follow the steps to see whether any problems are found.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is intermittent

Enable the WiFi logging by holding the Option key and click on the WiFi icon

[image]

Then go here `/var/log/wifi.log` (paste in Finder Go to Folder)

Open that file and monitor it, then report to us what happens.

It will keep recording till you turn it off with Option key WiFi.

**Most Common problem** is the DNS server.

DNS is responsible in translating your human name for your WiFi to its numerical address so it can talk to it.

In System Preferences > Network > Advanced > DNS

add `8.8.8.8` as DNS to the existing ones

Comment: A better place, then using Finder, to monitor the file would be directly from the Console app in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`. Then in the left column click on the **/var/log** folder and select **wifi.log**. You can then see input in real time and search too.

Comment: JSYK Even without Enable Wi-Fi Logging turned on, there is a small amount of normal logging that takes place for Wi-Fi, while turning logging on generates a greater amount of it containing different information.

Comment: @user3439894 JSYK, Apple decided to have the Option to Enable WiFi Logging for a reason.

Comment: @user3439894 JSYK, those are the same files in Console and in /var/log/wifi.log. When opening the file in /var/log/ it opens with Console app.