# Network connection timeouts on MacBook Pro

Tags: network

I have an Apple MacBook Pro with Mac OS Mojave 10.14.4 running.
Since 10.14.2 or 10.14.3 (I can't remember) the internet connection
times out every 2 minutes or so. It takes then from 20 sec to 1 min to load a web page. This happens for Chrome, Firefox and Safari-Browser, which I tested. This happens whether I use WiFi-connection or Ethernet-cable.
A typical ping for my WiFi-connection looks as follows:

MacBook-Pro:~$ ping 8.8.8.8

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=56 ttl=120 time=15.381 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=57 ttl=120 time=18.708 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=58 ttl=120 time=13.254 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=59 ttl=120 time=937.689 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=60 ttl=120 time=1901.038 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=61 ttl=120 time=2934.408 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=62 ttl=120 time=3958.543 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=63 ttl=120 time=4908.217 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=64 ttl=120 time=5905.401 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=65 ttl=120 time=6842.036 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 72
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=66 ttl=120 time=7862.743 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 74
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=67 ttl=120 time=8889.559 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 76
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=68 ttl=120 time=9843.350 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 78
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=69 ttl=120 time=10892.615 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 80
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=70 ttl=120 time=11936.543 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 82
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=71 ttl=120 time=12980.791 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 84
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=72 ttl=120 time=13820.231 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 86
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=73 ttl=120 time=14764.972 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 88
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=74 ttl=120 time=15707.589 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 90
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=76 ttl=120 time=15748.127 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 92
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=78 ttl=120 time=15691.715 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=79 ttl=120 time=14686.667 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=80 ttl=120 time=13683.104 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=81 ttl=120 time=12678.182 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=82 ttl=120 time=11673.334 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=83 ttl=120 time=10668.399 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=84 ttl=120 time=9664.758 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=85 ttl=120 time=8661.137 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=94 ttl=120 time=28.665 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=95 ttl=120 time=15.928 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=96 ttl=120 time=15.640 ms
```

This repeats periodically. The same behaviour, when I switch off WiFi and put an Ethernet cable onto the computer. As I have another computer in my home network having no network problems this seems to be a problem of this machine, but I have no idea what might cause it.

Any help is greatly welcome!
Wolfgang

Comment: How about pinging *internal* nodes like the router?  Do you still have the latency?  Do you disable WiFi when using Ethernet?

Comment: I tested with WiFi disabled and enabled when using Ethernet - same behaviour. When I ping another computer in my home network I get no request timeouts, but quite strong variations in response time (factor 20).

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked previously in this site ([1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74419/wifi-wont-connect-connection-timeout-mac), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335742/macbook-air-wifi-connection-timeout-problem)), and in many other forums, but not answered particularly well. I have, on a couple of occasions, experienced bouts of chronic network timeouts, but they have "cured themselves" after a restart. Your problem sounds persistent, and my curiosity was piqued. So here's what I found:

From [OSX Daily is an approach that requires you delete a set of files in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`](http://osxdaily.com/2016/05/14/fix-wifi-connection-timeout-error-mac/). Apparently these are files the system generates, but it sounds like you'll need to re-enter the settings, and that could be an effort if you've made a lot of WiFi connections. The procedure is basically as follows:

- Turn off Wi-Fi in System Preferences or menu bar.
- Remove aall Thunderbolt or USB devoces connected
- Create a backup folder & copy the files you will delete below into it

Here's the list of files to be copied to a backup folder, and then deleted from: `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`:

```
- com.apple.airport.preferences.plist  
- com.apple.airport.preferences.plist-new   
- com.apple.network.identification.plist   
- NetworkInterfaces.plist  
-  preferences.plist
```

There is also [this article from OSX Tips](https://osxtips.net/how-to-fix-wi-fi-timeout-connection/) that, essentially, prescribes the same approach. It's recent vintage (March, 2019), and that could be taken as some sort of affirmation that it still works?

So, if you're in the mood to be a [guinea pig](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guinea%20pig), try this, and let us know if it worked!

Comment: I have in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration the following files:                             NetworkInterfaces.plist             com.apple.smb.server.plist
com.apple.Boot.plist                com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist
com.apple.accounts.exists.plist     preferences.plist
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist                                                                                      I deleted the first and the two last and rebooted. When I chose my home WLAN (the data were still present) I got the same timeout problem as before.

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't resolve the issue. Perhaps [this one](http://osxdaily.com/2018/11/19/fix-macos-mojave-wifi-problems/) will yield better results?

Comment: I followed every advice on the page, including a reinstall of Mojave - no effect. However, I noticed, if I boot into safe mode, the request timeouts seem to be gone.     What does this tell me?

Comment: @woju: Not sure... according to [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262), wifi may not even be available. Let me think on this & I'll follow up later. I've got to run now.

Comment: I was using Ethernet cable in safe mode.

Comment: @woju: Right... Here's my thought: You've invested time and effort in the assumption that (because your other host doesn't have these same issues) the issue is with the Mac. It makes sense to me to try to confirm that assumption before proceeding w/ Mac troubleshooting. Can you first verify that both machines are on the same subnet, and have the same routing to the Internet, DNS, etc? ([try traceroute or similar](https://www.wikihow.com/Traceroute)) If there's an easy way to "swap" situations for the two machines, try that also to see if the problem follows the location or the machine.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Testing the assumptions is a good idea. I did the following:  1) Plugging the ethernet cable to my linux-notebook: no network problem. Plugging the same cable to my MacBook: the reported timeouts. I checked in both cases the traceroute, but couldn't make out any difference (as far as I am aware)               2) I took the MacBook to my office and tested in the WLAN there, and wow: no network problem, no timeouts!                                    What does this mean? Is it the router??

Comment: Thank you for your help! Testing the assumptions is a good idea. I did the following:  1) Plugging the ethernet cable to my linux-notebook: no network problem. Plugging the same cable to my MacBook: the reported timeouts. I checked in both cases the traceroute, but couldn't make out any difference (as far as I am aware)               2) I took the MacBook to my office and tested in the WLAN there, and wow: no network problem, no timeouts!                                    What does this mean? Is it the router??

Comment: @woju: The evidence seems to indicate that it's not a Mac problem. I say that because of what you've reported on the experience with the Mac on your work network, but that assumes it's not some strange interaction between your Mac and your network. I suppose it's worth taking a look at a more complete picture of the network activity on your Mac. Would you be willing to try [this approach](http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/07/watch-network-traffic-mac-os-x-nettop/) using `nettop`?

Comment: I invoked nettop and found some strange network activity associated with one of my two mail accounts. I deleted the account and recreated it afresh - and now the network works without problems. This was the crux! Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: @woju: Glad I could help. Turns out my initial guess at the source of your problem was just incorrect. In retrospect, `nettop` should have been the first move to eliminate the possibility of an errant app on your Mac. So we've both learned something! :)